# Message box in C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, messagebox

I want to display a "SUCCESSFUL" pop-up message after executing my program in C in Linux.

It should run on both KDE and GNOME. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(C++) MessageBox for Linux like in MS Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384125/c-messagebox-for-linux-like-in-ms-windows)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5041337/781723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [desktop notifications](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/index.html).  I believe both KDE and GNOME support them.  Here is a (Gtk+-based) [library](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libnotify/) you can use for your program's end.

Comment: http://git.gnome.org/browse/libnotify/tree/tests/test-basic.c might be what you want

Comment: Both are not found, bro. I know that this is old, but it would be nice if updated.

Answer (score 0):

Zenity (GNOME) and kdialog (KDE) are similar in a lot of respects.  Both will let you pop up a GUI notification.  If you just want to send something to the notification area in gnome notify-send does the trick.  I believe that kdialog will allow you to do something similar in KDE.  I don't know of a common tool between the two UIs.