# Message box in C in Linux

Tags: linux, c

I want to get a pop up message "SUCCESSFUL" after the execution my program in C in Linux?

the thing is that , it should run on both KDE and GNOME.

How can i do message box here?

Comment: I think this is more programming related.

Comment: Practically any sane solution will work on both and there is a great chance it will run on Mac OS X and Windows as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Message box in C in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037676/message-box-in-c-in-linux)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message box in C in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037676/message-box-in-c-in-linux)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5037676/781723

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For GNOME you may use [zenity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity). For example:

```
$ your_program && zenity --info --text="SUCCESSFUL"
```

For KDE use kdialog

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something in QT?
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_create_interactive_messagebox_for_getting_user_response_in_Qt_for_Symbian

Take a look there, it's a more complicated example, but you could just change the message to whatever you wanted after your program completes.

You could make a single button pop up that says "Code Complete" and when they click on it it exits?