# Pop-up message boxes with buttons using SDL 1.2?

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

For reasons I can't change, I have to program using the last version of SDL1.2. I need to be able to create pop-up windows with options (such as yes/no windows), and it only needs to support Linux because the software I'm working on already has pop-ups implemented for Windows and MacOS.

How would I go about doing this, without using a GUI toolkit? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384125/c-messagebox-for-linux-like-in-ms-windows) question already, but the answers all suggest using toolkits which bring in extra dependencies.

Comment: X11?  Wayland?  Linux framebuffer?

Comment: one easy way is to draw both the window and the text inside in a gfx editor, then you fudge with the buttons and its done.

Comment: BTW: extra dependencies should be fine, they make things so much easier.

Comment: There are tons of tiny libraries that do this. Like https://github.com/btzy/nativefiledialog-extended